# Trigger sometimes fails with duplicate key error

Tags: postgresql, triggers, race-condition

I'm using a PostgreSQL RDS instance in AWS. Basically, there is a query that inserts data into a first table, let's call it `table`. The data there can have duplicates in some fields (except for the primary key obviously).

Then there is the trigger that updates another table, `infotable`, allowing no duplicates.

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_infotable AFTER INSERT ON table
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_infotable();
```

The relevant part of the trigger function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_infotable() RETURNS trigger AS $insert_infotable$
    BEGIN   
        --some irrelevant code
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM infotable WHERE col1 = NEW.col1 AND col2 = NEW.col2) THEN
            INSERT INTO infotable(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) values (--some values--);
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$insert_infotable$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The table `infotable` has a UNIQUE constraint on the columns `col1` and `col2`.

In general all is working fine, but rarely, about once in 1k inserts, the trigger returns an error 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_col1_and_col2"' for table `infotable`. Which shouldn't happen since there is the `IF NOT EXISTS` part in the trigger function.

The first question is what might be the cause of this? The only thing I can think of is races where two users are getting the same info simultaneously, both trigger the trigger but then one updates the second table via trigger and the second user gets the duplicate error. And because of that his whole insert query fails, including the insert to the main `table`.

If that's the case, what can I do about it? Is using a lock on insert a good idea for a table that is supposed to have 100+ users inserting data simultaneously?

And if yes, what type of lock should I use and **what table should I lock** -- the main table, or the second one, which gets modified by the trigger? (or I guess should I have the lock with my main insert statement or inside the trigger function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a race condition. Two such triggers running concurrently won't see each other's modifications, because the transactions are not yet committed.

Since you have a unique constraint on `infotable`, you can simply use

```
INSERT INTO infotable ...
ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) DO NOTHING;
```